# preg_match_all returning too many results

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php 

$string = "String is '@Name Surname test @Secondname Surname tomas poas tomas'"

preg_match_all("/@(\w+)(\s)(\w+)/", $string, $matches);
```

I want extract:

```
[
0 => '@Name Surname',
1 => '@Secondname Surname',
]
```

What I get;

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '@Name Surname',
    1 => '@Secondname Surname',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Name',
    1 => 'Secondname',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => ' ',
    1 => ' ',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Surname',
    1 => 'Surname',
  ),
)
```

Comment: That is how `preg_match_all()` works. 1 subArray = entire Match, 2subArray 1 Capturing group, 3subArray 2 Capturing group, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and capture groups work.

If you just want the whole names, you need to reduce that to what you need only or use non-capturing parenthesis.

For example:

```
preg_match_all("/(@\w+\s\w+)/", $string, $matches);
```

Note that by default:

> Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern
>   matches, $matches[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is an array of strings matched by the first
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

So you really don't need to capture anything in your case:

```
preg_match_all("/@\w+\s\w+/", $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression (remove the capture group to spaces)

```
/@\w+\s\w+/
```

Test it here:

https://regex101.com/r/cL5xH2/2

Result:

```
[
0 => '@Name Surname',
1 => '@Secondname Surname',
]
```